# How to maintain Session states on multithreads

Tags: javascript, node.js, multithreading, session

Let's say i am running multi thread programming in nodejs (using some npm module for multi threading) and maintaining user sessions through it.
In this scenario, how to maintain session states?

Comment: "using some npm module for multi threading" --- like what?

Comment: There are some, Eg: (jxcore)https://github.com/jxcore/jxcore

Comment: Then check their documentation about synchronisation primitives it provides.

Comment: Thank you for your ans. if i found the answer there, i wouldn't have asked the question here